# Theme not working in android

Tags: android, android-theme

I added theme changing Preference i.e changing dark theme,primary color,accent color.When i select dark theme it only changes setting activity theme not in whole app and primary color and accent color also not changing.
Code are given below.

**setting activity.java**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.support.annotation.ColorInt;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.afollestad.materialdialogs.color.ColorChooserDialog;
import com.dps.brt.Widget.Preference;
import com.dps.brt.Widget.Utils;

public class SettingActivity extends ThemedActivity implements ColorChooserDialog.ColorCallback{
@Override
protected int darkTheme() {
    return R.style.AppThemeDark;
}

@Override
protected int lightTheme() {
    return R.style.AppTheme;
}

@SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
public void onColorSelection(@NonNull ColorChooserDialog colorChooserDialog, @ColorInt int color) {
    if (colorChooserDialog.isAccentMode()) {
        accentColor(color);
    } else {
        primaryColor(color);
    }
    recreate();
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    boolean darkTheme = isDarkTheme();
    int primaryColor = primaryColor();
    int accentColor = accentColor();
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.setting);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Setting");
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.tc, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }

}
public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.theme);
        findPreference("dark_theme").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(android.preference.Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                if (getActivity() != null) {
                    getActivity().recreate();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        Preference primaryColor = (Preference) findPreference("primary_color");
        primaryColor.setColor(((ThemedActivity) getActivity()).primaryColor(), Utils.resolveColor(getActivity(), R.attr.colorAccent));
        primaryColor.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(android.preference.Preference preference) {
                SettingActivity act = (SettingActivity) getActivity();
                if (act == null) {
                    return false;
                }
                new ColorChooserDialog.Builder(act, preference.getTitleRes())
                        .preselect(act.primaryColor())
                        .backButton(R.string.back)
                        .doneButton(R.string.done)
                        .cancelButton(android.R.string.cancel)
                        .show();
                return true;
            }
        });


        Preference accentColor = (Preference) findPreference("accent_color");
        accentColor.setColor(((ThemedActivity) getActivity()).accentColor(), Utils.resolveColor(getActivity(), R.attr.colorAccent));
        accentColor.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(android.preference.Preference preference) {
                SettingActivity act = (SettingActivity) getActivity();
                if (act == null) {
                    return false;
                }
                new ColorChooserDialog.Builder(act, preference.getTitleRes())
                        .preselect(act.accentColor())
                        .accentMode(true)
                        .backButton(R.string.back)
                        .doneButton(R.string.done)
                        .cancelButton(android.R.string.cancel)
                        .show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {SettingActivity.this.finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**Base theme activity**

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.annotation.ColorInt;
import android.support.annotation.FloatRange;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.afollestad.materialdialogs.internal.ThemeSingleton;
import com.dps.brt.Widget.PrefUtils;

public abstract class ThemedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private boolean mLastDarkTheme;
private int mLastPrimaryColor;
private int mLastAccentColor;

@ColorInt
public static int shiftColor(@ColorInt int color, @FloatRange(from = 0.0f, to = 2.0f) float by) {
    if (by == 1f) {
        return color;
    }
    float[] hsv = new float[3];
    Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);
    hsv[2] *= by; // value component
    return Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
}

@ColorInt
public static int shiftColorDown(@ColorInt int color) {
    return shiftColor(color, 0.9f);
}

protected int darkTheme() {
    return R.style.AppThemeDark;
}

protected int lightTheme() {
    return R.style.AppTheme;
}

public boolean isDarkTheme() {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean(PrefUtils.DARK_THEME, false);
}

public int primaryColor() {
    String key = PrefUtils.PRIMARY_COLOR_PREFIX;
    if (mLastDarkTheme) {
        key += "_dark";
    } else {
        key += "_light";
    }
    final int defaultColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, mLastDarkTheme ?
            R.color.dark_theme_gray : R.color.material_indigo_500);
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt(key, defaultColor);
}

protected void primaryColor(int newColor) {
    String key = PrefUtils.PRIMARY_COLOR_PREFIX;
    if (mLastDarkTheme) {
        key += "_dark";
    } else {
        key += "_light";
    }
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putInt(key, newColor).apply();
}

public int primaryColorDark() {
    return shiftColorDown(primaryColor());
}

public int accentColor() {
    String key = PrefUtils.ACCENT_COLOR_PREFIX;
    if (mLastDarkTheme) {
        key += "_dark";
    } else {
        key += "_light";
    }
    final int defaultColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.material_pink_500);
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt(key, defaultColor);
}

protected void accentColor(int newColor) {
    String key = PrefUtils.ACCENT_COLOR_PREFIX;
    if (mLastDarkTheme) {
        key += "_dark";
    } else {
        key += "_light";
    }
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putInt(key, newColor).apply();
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mLastDarkTheme = isDarkTheme();
    mLastPrimaryColor = primaryColor();
    mLastAccentColor = accentColor();
    ColorStateList sl = ColorStateList.valueOf(mLastAccentColor);
    ThemeSingleton.get().positiveColor = sl;
    ThemeSingleton.get().neutralColor = sl;
    ThemeSingleton.get().negativeColor = sl;
    ThemeSingleton.get().widgetColor = mLastAccentColor;
    setTheme(mLastDarkTheme ? darkTheme() : lightTheme());
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        // Sets color of entry in the system recents page
        ActivityManager.TaskDescription td = new ActivityManager.TaskDescription(
                getString(R.string.app_name),
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher),
                primaryColor());
        setTaskDescription(td);
    }

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(primaryColor()));
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && hasColoredBars()) {
        final int dark = primaryColorDark();
        if (allowStatusBarColoring()) {
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(dark);
        } else {
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.transparent));
        }
    }
}

protected boolean allowStatusBarColoring() {
    return false;
}

protected boolean hasColoredBars() {
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    boolean darkTheme = isDarkTheme();
    int primaryColor = primaryColor();
    int accentColor = accentColor();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you need to call `recreate()` in the Main activity. In the code you provided, you call `recreate()` in the Settings activity which is why the theme applies correctly. When you go back to the Main activity, it is not recreated but only resumed, so the theme is never applied; `onCreate()` is not called.